# How to designate a child view within a TabControl for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, modern-ui

I'm fairly new to wpf and I'm designing a UI with Modern UI.  I've got a basic ModernUI Modern Tab with four different Linked DisplayName's showing the source of the child views as shown below:

```
    <mui:ModernTab Layout="Tab" SelectedSource="/Views/SampleTabView/SampleTabView1.xaml">
        <mui:ModernTab.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Sample View 1" Source="/Views/SampleTabView/SampleTabView1.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Sample View 2" Source="/Views/SampleTabView/SampleTabView2.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Sample View 3" Source="/Views/SampleTabView/SampleTabView3.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Sample View 4" Source="/Views/SampleTabView/SampleTabView4.xaml" />
        </mui:ModernTab.Links>
    </mui:ModernTab>
```

But what I'm wondering is in the TabControl is there a way to designate a child view like I do with the Source in ModernTab's.  Below is a sample of my code for the TabControl:

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Sample View 1">
            View 1
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Sample View 2">
            View 2
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Sample View 3">
            View 3
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Sample View 4">
            View 4
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope AFAIK there is no such thing but I guess these XAML files are `UserControl`s.

So you could simply do:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Sample View 1">
        <local:SampleTabView1></local:SampleTabView1>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Sample View 2">
        <local:SampleTabView2></local:SampleTabView2>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Sample View 3">
        <local:SampleTabView3></local:SampleTabView3>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Sample View 4">
        <local:SampleTabView4></local:SampleTabView4>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Am I missing something?...

Comment: How do you define local in the xaml file?

Comment: And it is a UserControl

Comment: @MarkBasler Like this `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TheNamespace.That.Contains.The.Views"`

Comment: And if they are in another assembly: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TheNamespace.That.Contains.The.Views;assembly=The.Other.Assembly"`

Comment: Yup that Did it.  I appreciate it.